# Finite sum equaling Kronecker Delta

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

could anyone help understand how 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-r}\binom{n-r}{j}*(-1)^{j} = [1 + (-1)]^{n-r}$$

I see that if $j=0$, i get $1=1^{n-r}$, and if $j=n-r$, i get $(-1)^{n-r},$ but what about the rest of the terms, and how did the parenthesis come about? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out "binomial expansion"

Answer (score 1):

That's the binomial theorem. We have (in general)
$$ (a+b)^{n-r} = \sum_{j=0}^{n-r} \binom{n-r}j a^{n-r-j}b^j $$
Now let $a = 1$ and $b = (-1)$, this gives
$$ (1+(-1))^{n-r} = \sum_{j=0}^{n-r} \binom{n-r}j (-1)^j $$
as $1^{n-r-j} = 1$ for all $j$.

Comment: haha fantastic! Can't believe i didn't notice the binomial theorem there. Thanks!